# Recursively searching for top level of matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have some HTML as shown below, and I want to search for descendants of my `#top` element that have the `foo` class.  However, I only want to find elements that are not subelements of other elements that I find.  That is, although generally I want to search for `foo` elements recursively, I do not want to recurse into `foo` elements.

```
<div class="foo" id="top">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="foo"> <!-- Find this !-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo"> <!-- Find this !-->
        <div class="foo"> <!-- Do not find this, because we already found parent !-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I best do this using Javascript/jQuery?

**Edit:** There's been some confusion around this. The example above is meant to illustrate the problem, but it doesn't encapsulate every edge case that a general solution should solve, so I've created a more complex example in the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JQNyW/1/

Comment: Should we assume that this isn't the exact structure, so the levels of nesting could actually vary a bit?

Comment: @CrazyTrain, yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
$('#top').find('.foo').filter(function () { // while selecting ignore parent which also has foo
    return $(this).parents('.foo').length == 1; //length is 1 since the #top also has foo
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ykwZ/)**

Or

```
$('#top').find('.foo').filter(function () {
    return $(this).parents('.foo:not("#top")').length == 0
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: +1 though you could remove the `:not("#top")` since `.find()` doesn't look at the context node.

Comment: Crap, Thanks you are right.. /:(. hard day of work.. :) dont know what i am thinking... time to party..

Comment: Well, not quite, because I don't want to make any assumptions about the outside structure of what I provided... for example, `#top` could be inside another `foo`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYytY/3/.  But I suppose this minor tweak to your solution would solve that problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYytY/4/

Comment: @Eric: Another possibility would be to use `.parentsUntil()` inside the filter. `return $(this).parentsUntil("#top").filter('.foo').length == 0;`

Comment: ...or even `return $(this).parents("#top .foo").length == 0;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Second on is the best one you can get...  `$('#top').find('.foo').filter(function () {
    return $(this).parents("#top .foo").length == 0;
}).css('color', 'red');`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the children() or find() separately as they dont need to be chain to access the children's children and it makes it a cleaner, optimized and faster to process, like this:

```
 $('#top').children('.foo').attr('this','yeah');

 $('#top').find('> .foo',this).attr('child','yes');
```

take a look in the console, it add the att() to the first element only.

depending on your needs refer to the docs in jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/children/

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector:

```
#top > .foo, :not(.foo) > .foo
```

either in jQuery or in native JavaScript.